# Change between multiple view controllers causing app to crash; Tab View; Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Apologies for this one, I'm sure that I'm missing a swift fundamental here.
I have a navigation app that I'm working on in swift.
Earlier on I made it as a single view and have changed it to a tab bar controller application.

In the background the location manager does its work and when is does the update locations work it displays the lat and long on a label.
When the app was a single view app this was no problem however now that it is a tab bar app, as soon as I change to a different tab when the location manager function fires it crashes the app with the following code (which I suspect means nothing much on its own) `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10039bb54`

I strongly suspect that I am doing something fundamentally wrong with trying to update a label on a view controller that is not active at the time.

```
distanceLabel.text = "Currently \(distanceText) from destination"
lbl_location.text = String(mylat) + ", " + String(mylong)
```

I have copied in all of my code below only taking out a few sensitive bits so that you can see the big picture.

Open to constructive feedback as to better coding practices.

Thanks

Bruce

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //in the original view controller which has now been incorporated into tabs    
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_location: UILabel!
    //on a new view controller on another tab
    @IBOutlet weak var employeeNameSetup: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var employeeNumberSetup: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactNumberSetup: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var managerNameSetup: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var managerEmailSetup: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var adminPasswordSetup: UITextField!


    @IBAction func setAppDefaults(_ sender: Any) {
        if (employeeNameSetup.text?.isEmpty)! || (employeeNumberSetup.text?.isEmpty)! || (contactNumberSetup.text?.isEmpty)! || (managerNameSetup.text?.isEmpty)! || (managerEmailSetup.text?.isEmpty)!{
            let noGoAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Insufficient Fields Filled out", message: "Only the Password field is optional, please fill out all other fields before pressing button", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .default, handler: nil)
            noGoAlert.addAction(defaultAction)
            present(noGoAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(employeeNameSetup.text, forKey: "employeeName")
            defaults.set(employeeNumberSetup.text, forKey: "employeeNumber")
            defaults.set(contactNumberSetup.text, forKey: "contactNumber")
            defaults.set(managerNameSetup.text, forKey: "managerName")
            defaults.set(managerEmailSetup.text, forKey: "managerEmail")
        }

    }

    @IBAction func submit_button(_ sender: Any) {
    uploadData()
    }

    let location_process = CLLocationManager()

    var mylat :Double = 0
    var mylong :Double = 0
    var destination = CLLocation(latitude: #####, longitude: #####)
    var distanceToDest :Int = 0
    var dburl = NSURL(string: "#########")
    let contact_name = "#####"
    let contact_number = "#####"
    let unique_id = "###"
    let employee_number = "#####"
    var distanceText = ""
    var runOnce = false
    var isAdmin = false
    var adminPassword = "#######"

    func sendEmail(messageText: String){
        let url = URL (string: "########")
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let paramtosend = #########
        request.httpBody = paramtosend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
        task.resume()
    }



    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let mylocation = locations[0]
        mylat = mylocation.coordinate.latitude
        mylong = mylocation.coordinate.longitude


        distanceToDest = Int(mylocation.distance(from: destination))
        if distanceToDest > 1000 {
            distanceText = String(Int(distanceToDest/1000))
            distanceText = distanceText + " km"
        }
        else if distanceToDest < 100 {

            let current_date_time = Date()
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .medium
            formatter.timeStyle = .medium
            formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd MMM yyyy"
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent

            let timestamp = formatter.string(from: current_date_time)
            if !runOnce {
                sendEmail(messageText: "\(contact_name); Employee \(employee_number) Arrived at destination \(destination.coordinate.latitude), \(destination.coordinate.longitude) at \(timestamp)")
            }
            distanceText = String(distanceToDest)
            distanceText = distanceText + " m"
            runOnce = true
        }
        else {
            distanceText = String(distanceToDest)
            distanceText = distanceText + " m"
        }
        distanceLabel.text = "Currently \(distanceText) from destination"
        lbl_location.text = String(mylat) + ", " + String(mylong)

        uploadData()

    }


    @IBAction func uploadData()
    {

        var httprequest = URLRequest(url: dburl! as URL)
        httprequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        var dataString = "####" // starting POST string with a secretWord

        // the POST string has entries separated by &
        dataString = dataString + "&unique_id=" + unique_id
        dataString = dataString + "&mylat=" + String(mylat) // add items as name and value
        dataString = dataString + "&mylong=" + String(mylong)
        dataString = dataString + "&contact_name=" + contact_name
        dataString = dataString + "&contact_number=" + contact_number
        dataString = dataString + "&employee_number=" + employee_number

        let current_date_time = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .medium
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm dd MMM yyyy"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent

        let timestamp = formatter.string(from: current_date_time)



        dataString = dataString + "&timestamp=" + timestamp

        // convert the post string to utf8 format

        let dataD = dataString.data(using: .utf8) // convert to utf8 string

        do
        {

            // the upload task, uploadJob, is defined here

            let uploadJob = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: httprequest, from: dataD!)

            //let uploadJob = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: httprequest, from: dataD)

            uploadJob.resume()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        location_process.delegate = self
        location_process.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        location_process.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        location_process.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        location_process.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        {

            location_process.distanceFilter = 50
            location_process.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            location_process.startUpdatingLocation()
        }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Comment: This error indicates that you're trying to unwrap an optional that has a nil value. Check if all your outlets are connected properly. If the error still persists please share the exact line when the error happens.

Comment: Thanks NSAdi, Would the outlets not being connected properly make the code run OK when on the view controller that contains that component is active but error out when we click onto another view controller?

Comment: When you try to load a ViewController that has disconnected outlets it result a crash. That should narrow it down.

Comment: you have to stop location manager before you shift to an other viewCotroller.

Comment: @Bruce did you fix it?

Comment: Yes I did, turns out there were lots of problems with teaching yourself from code snippets.  I am going back to the basics to pick up some better Swift practices and fundamentals so I don't code myself into a corner like this again.